# Mongoose, nodejs, full text search

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, full-text-search

I am trying setting up a simple keywords full text search using Mongoose and nodejs, this is the code so far:

```
var db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', config.mongoDbName)
    , ContSchema = Schema({
        'idUser': String,
        'title': String,
        'category': String,
        'slug': String,
        'description': String
      })
      .index({
      'title':'text',
      'description':'text'
    })
 , ContModel = db.model('Cont', ContSchema);

db.on('error', function (err) {

        console.error.bind(console, 'Mongoose connection error:' + err);
    });
    db.once('open', function () {

      process.stdout.write('Connection to mongodb db done...');
    });
```

then i do search query:

```
var getAllBy = function (limit, offset, keywords) {

       var sort
        , find
        , findScore;

       if (!!keywords) {

        find = {'$text':{'$search':keywords}};
        findScore = {'score':{'$meta':'textMatchScore'}};
        sort = {'score':{'$meta':'textMatchScore'}};

       } else {

        sort = {'_id':'desc'};
       }

       return new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        ContModel.find(find, findScore).limit(limit).skip(offset).sort(sort).exec(function (err, data) {

          if (err){

            reject(err);
          } else {

            resolve(data);
          }
        });
       });
}
```

It doesnt work it returns this error in console:  **MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue bad sort specification**

I am actually unable to find the real problem with this, can you please help me out?

thank you

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using? The text search syntax used here is only available from the 2.6 release

Comment: @Neil Lunn MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4

Comment: FYI You can have a newer shell and connect to an older server. So it was really the "server version" I was asking about.

Comment: @NeilLunn sec i cant find how to check the server version :D

Comment: @NeilLunn running mongod: **2014-09-23T10:24:47.624+0200 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.4** is this the correct info? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your keywords are incorrect here, see the correct syntax under the [**`$meta`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/meta/) operator, which currently only has "textScore":

```js
  find = {'$text':{'$search':keywords}};
  findScore = {'score':{'$meta':'textScore'}};
  sort = {'score': {'$meta':'textScore'} }
```

Comment: seems something is moving on , thanks but see now i get this : **MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unsupported $meta operator: textMatchScore**

Comment: @sbaaaang So like I said, check the server version `db.serverStatus().version` will do that. But I mainly see that you have not changed anything. The $meta keyword is "textScore" not "textMatchScore"

Comment: yeah sorry didnt noticed that change, i copy pasted your full code same error appears

Comment: i confirm from mongo shell db.serverStatus().version = 2.6.4

Comment: @sbaaaang How can the same error appear if you changed the code? The error specifies the incorrect value used here.

Comment: gosh , sorry, error now is : **MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue can't have a non-$meta sort on a $meta projection** :(

Comment: @sbaaaang Just use the $meta form of projection then. I think I still have my head in aggregate space after the last two hours of it.

Comment: eheheh thanks just i would like to know what is the $meta form protection i tryed googling but no helpful results ahhhh im getting crazy :D

Comment: @sbaaaang Like you did originally, and I also updated the answer content to show the correct form if you read it.